# Python не видит папку в пайтон-пакете, при обращении к ней из другого пайтон-пакета

Tags: python, импорт, path, kaldi, vosk

Python 3.9

Имею такую структуру проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь из пакета *user_interface*, файла *main*, запустить скрипт *synth_recog*, который лежит в соседнем пакете *back_end*. В этом скрипте происходит импорт файлов из папки *vosk_small_model_ru*, с помощью библиотеки vosk.

```
self.model = Model('path_to/vosk_small_model_ru')
```

При абсолютном импорте все работает. Но при относительном нет.
(Вот относительный импорт)

```
self.model = Model('../back_end/vosk_small_model_ru')
```

В чем проблема? **Почему не работает через относительный путь?** Вариант с получением пути через *os.path.abspath* и последующей его подстановкой в *Model*, не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path

project_root = Path(__file__).parent.parent
self.model = Model(project_root / 'back_end' / 'vosk_small_model_ru')
```